# Close mysqli database connections after AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax, database, mysqli, connection

I'm handling my ajax calls in an ajax.php that establishes a database connection using the mysqli_connect() function and closing the connection right using the mysqli_close() function before the echo and exit.

Still it seems connections remain open, cause after a certain amount of ajax calls I'm getting the 'To many connections' error.

So now i'm wondering, what is the best way to make sure my all db connections are closed after each call? Is there a way to check how many connections are currently open to troubleshoot the problem?

ajax.php:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// ....some PHP code...

echo 'result';
mysqli_close($con);
exit();
```

Comment: Unless you use persistent connections, they will be closed automatically when the script ends. You are probably doing more ajax calls than you realize.

Comment: I've added a simplyfied version of the ajax.php

Comment: You could [kill the threads](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.kill.php) before closing.

Comment: @PimVanVlaenderen Now that you are starting to learn PHP is the right moment to get rid of mysqli_...() functions and start using PDO. Take this as an advice. You will thank me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
$connection = new mysqli(.....)

// stuff to do 

$thread = $connection->thread_id;
$connection->kill($thread);
```

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.kill.php):

> This function is used to ask the server to kill a MySQL thread
>   specified by the processid parameter. This value must be retrieved by
>   calling the mysqli_thread_id() function.